# Keep padding inside div

Tags: html, css

I'm using a flexslider gallery with captions in Bootstrap and I want to keep the text at the bottom of the caption box with the semi-transparent padding filling the entire height of the slideshow box. I've set the padding to 100% but it runs out of the top of the box and covers up my nav bar.

I'm guessing this is a simple fix but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Link to site: http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/html/project-01.html

CSS:

```
.flexslider{
background:none!important;
border:none!important;
box-shadow:none!important;
margin:0px -15px 0px 0px!important;
}

.right {
padding-top: 100%!important;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.flex-caption {
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
z-index: 1;
padding: 20px;
font-size: 11px;
width: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
        <!-- slideshow gallery -->          
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
            <div class="flexslider">
              <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                  <img src="img/project-1_01.jpg" />
                  <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                        Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                        Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                        This home exudes quiet, California Fescue, Berkeley Sedge, Coyote Needle Grass, along with large specimen and Redwoods comprise the restorative Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, California Fescue, Berkeley Sedge.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="img/project-1_02.jpg" />
                  <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                        Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                        Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                        Grass, along with large specimen and Redwoods comprise the restorative Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="img/project-1_03.jpg" />
                  <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                      Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                      Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                      Exude quiet, California Fescue, Berkeley Sedge, Coyote Needle Grass, along with large specimen and Redwoods.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="img/project-1_04.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="img/project-1_05.jpg" />
                  <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                        Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                        Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                        Coyote Needle Grass, along with large specimen and Redwoods comprise the restorative allows this home to exude quiet, Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, California Fescue, Berkeley Sedge, Coyote Needle Grass, along.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="img/project-1_06.jpg" />
                  <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                        Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                        Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                        Large specimen and Redwoods comprise the restorative Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, California Fescue, Berkeley Sedge, Coyote Needle Grass.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="img/project-1_07.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="img/project-1_08.jpg" />
                  <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                        Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                        Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                        Fescue, Berkeley Sedge, Coyote Needle Grass, along with large specimen and Redwoods comprise the restorative Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, Restraint, minimalization.</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Percentage padding is relative to the *width* of the parent element, so it may not behave as you expect. I suggest using `height:100%` or `bottom:0;top:0;` for the translucent overlay and then create a child element for the text that is aligned to `bottom:0` of the overlay element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to set the container to `overflow: hidden;`:

```
.slides {overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: Quick and easy fix, will remember this moving forward. Thank you @ralph.m

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `box-sizing: padding-box`.  This is expiremental technology, but [it's pretty well supported in major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing).  I'd give it a go.  **Note that you may need to use [vendor prefixes](http://davidwalsh.name/vendor-prefixes) to get this to work properly in all broswers.**